How to read content of csv file stored in azure storage using powershell?
I want to fetch file names ( columns [TransferDate,DirectoryName,FileName,CreationDate] ) from a csv file stored in azure storage, but i dont want to store it locally.  I am running the script in automation runbook where i am comparing the file names from the csv to the files stored in one of the storage containers.
I tried doing this, but i dont know how to parse the text to get file names .  Is there any other way ?
$client = $csvcontainer.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("Filename")
$file = $client.DownloadText() 

This is the powershell script i have , when i run this in automation account it given an error shown below
$storageAccountName = "xyz"
$containerName = "archive"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $context

$fileblobs = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "test" -Context $context -blob "abc"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.Open($fileblobs).Sheets.Item(1)
$ws = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$rowMax = $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count



Is the file a Comma Separated Values file (*.csv) or an Excel Workbook (*.xlsx). If the former you can use ConvertFrom-Csv to parse an in-memory string without needing to store it in a file first. If the latter, the Excel COM objects can only work with files, but a 3rd party library might support reading from in-memory streams…

Thank you, I am able to parse using  ConvertFrom-Csv


I want to fetch file names (columns: TransferDate, DirectoryName, FileName, CreationDate) from a CSV file stored in Azure storage, but I don't want to store it locally.

I agree with Mclayton's comment. If the file is a CSV file, you can use the ConvertFrom-Csv cmdlet to parse the in-memory string without needing to store it in a file first.
In my environment, I have stored a CSV file in Azure Blob storage with the details below.
Portal:

Now, using the script below, I can fetch the filenames.
Script:
$storageAccountName = "venkat123"
$containerName = "test"
$blobname="test.csv"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount

$csvBlob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Blob $blobname -Context $context
$csvString = $csvBlob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()

# Parse the CSV string into objects
$csvObjects = $csvString | ConvertFrom-Csv
$fileNames = $csvObjects.FileName
$fileNames 

Output:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt


